# how to get the width of bootsrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I display an image in an Modal (filling the whole Modal).
The Modal-size has three states:

- 900
- 600
- and filling almost the whole page

For the third one I want to know the width.
Is that possible?
I tried `.width()` method (returns nothing)

Comment: Can you not make the image width 100% in the modal CSS?

Comment: As Dan Cundy pointed out 100% width makes sense, especially if you use bootstraps `img-responsive` class.

Comment: Yeah, either make the image responsive or put it in as a background with `background-size: cover`. You're working way too hard. If you must get the width programmatically, you'll have to use the modal `shown` callback. You can't get the size of a hidden element.

Comment: Dan Cundy is right thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tryto use `width:100%` in the style of the `<img>`